# How to get each gallery images' alt attribute, and then add them as a header after each of them

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

I want to give my wordpress gallery images some nice layout, but I don't even know how to start. Could you help me out?

This is  how far I've got, but I think this is wrong on so many levels. I want to have a figcaption under each image with their title. How should I approach this?

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

var alt = $(".attachment-thumbnail").attr("alt");
$('.attachment-thumbnail').after('<figcaption><h5 class="centered">', alt , ' </h5></figcaption>');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate like this:

```
$('.attachment-thumbnail').after('<figcaption><h5 class="centered">' + alt + '</h5></figcaption>')
```